# Converting int[] to bytes[] Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert an int[] to bytes . It gets converted also.

My code for conversion is this.

```
public static byte[] convertIntoBytes(int[] menuIds){
    byte[] byteConverted;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(menuIds.length * 4);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    intBuffer.put(menuIds);
    byteConverted = byteBuffer.array();
    for (int i = 0; i < 840; i++) {
        Log.d("Bytes sfter Insert", ""+byteConverted[i]);
    }
    return byteConverted;
}
```

Suppose i an inputting an int[] = {10,11,15,41,12,8,4,23,5,17,23,36,6}
Now i want the byte array to be like this 
{10,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,41,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,36,0,0,0,6,0,0,0}

But the byte array coming to be is

{0,0,0,10,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,41,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,36,0,0,0,6,}

Actually i am trying to get the byte array to be start from first position.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for the [`order(java.nio.ByteOrder)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) method? Default is `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN`, so have a go with `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
...
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(menuIds.length * 4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on [bits order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) on current machine.

Comment: by bit you mean byte?

Comment: @njzk2 yes byte, typo